# How to set border edges in HorizontalBarChartView

Tags: library, ios, charts

I need help creating this style BarChart, only the rounded end edges.

I'm using the library "ios-charts" but not have this feature. finally, recomended any library having this feature, rounded end edges and horizontal bar chart with negative, please

Attached a picture:

[image]